# Missing expiresIn Option in nestjs/jwt v10.2.0

Tags: jwt, nestjs

### Missing expiresIn Option in nestjs/jwt v10.2.0

I recently updated my NestJS project to version 10.2.0, and I noticed that the `expiresIn` option is no longer available in the `JwtService.signAsync` method. I couldn't find any information about this change in the release notes or documentation.

#### Issue Details

- **Package Version**: 10.2.0
- **Official Package Link**: [nestjs/jwt]

Typescript interface:

```
export interface JwtSignOptions extends jwt.SignOptions {
    secret?: string | Buffer;
    privateKey?: jwt.Secret;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad! It is edited now.

Comment: Seems that this is a known [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/jwt/issues/1369), and they even [fixed](https://github.com/nestjs/jwt/pull/1370) it, but, for whatever reason, did not yet merge the branch with the fix, if I'm interpreting this correctly.